# How to linearlize level curves at a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, algebraic-curves, implicit-function-theorem

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $(x_s, y_s)$ be a saddle point of $f(x,y)$ in $D$. That is to say,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_s, y_s) =&0, \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_s, y_s) =&0,
\end{align}
but that $f$ does not take the maximum or minimum value at $(x_s,y_s)$.
We can implicitly define the level curves through the saddle point by the condition, 
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = f(x_s, y_s).
\tag{1}
\label{eq: 1}
\end{equation} 
Let us write the explicit forms of these level curves as
\begin{align}
 y =& h_i(x), &i=&1,\dots,N,
\tag{2}
\label{eq: 2}
\end{align} 
where $N$ is the number of the contour lines passing through the saddle point. How can I calculate the derivative, 
\begin{align}
\frac{d h_i}{dx}(x_s,y_s)&,& i=&1,\dots,N,
\tag{3}
\label{eq: 3}
\end{align}
i.e., the slopes of the level curves at the saddle point?

I am confused because it looks like a $0/0$ indefinite form. Please note that by taking derivative of the both sides of eq. (\ref{eq: 1}) with respect to $x$, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \frac{dy}{dx} = 0,
\tag{4}
\label{eq: 4}
\end{equation} 
and if $\partial f/\partial y \not=0$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)}.
\tag{5}
\label{eq: 5}
\end{equation} 
However, at the saddle point,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_s,y_s) =& 0, 
\tag{6}
\label{eq: 6}
\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_s,y_s) =& 0, 
\tag{7}
\label{eq: 7}
\end{align}
and therefore it looks that as $(x,y) \rightarrow (x_s,y_s)$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} \rightarrow \frac{0}{0}. 
\tag{8}
\label{eq: 8}
\end{equation}

For some examples of $f(x,y)$, I can determine the level curves $\{h_i(x)\}$ explicitly, but still have difficulty to calculate $dh_i/dx$ at $(x_s,y_s)$ as it takes the $0/0$ indefinite form.

---

EDITED 2016-07-21 07:40 GMT+2
I replaced all occurrences of contour lines by level curves and added definition of a saddle point.

Comment: Ah so here comes in the Hessian.

Comment: What are contour lines, in your understanding? Lines of equal $f$? Am I right that you require the set of saddles to form a continuous line, of which the point $(x_s,y_s)$ is an element?

Comment: @keenPenguin Thank you for the comment. Yes, I meant by 'contour line' a line on which $f$ is constant. However, I now realized that I should refer to such a line as 'level curve' since 'contour line' may mean any line on a 2- or higher dimensional space. About the saddle, I was thinking it as an isolated point. By a saddle point, I meant a point where $\partial f/\partial x =0$ and $\partial f/\partial y = 0$ but where $f$ is neither maximum or minimum. At this point, I think two or more level curves cross each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the saddle point, you need to expand up to the second order and the Taylor development essentially becomes

$$f-f_0=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2,$$ (a parabolic hyperboloid) which you can factor as the product of two lines.